# what is the difference between [] and ([]) in python

Tags: python-3.x

this is an elementary question but I couldn't find any explanation on google.

```
print([])
```

prints

```
[]
```

but

```
print(([]))
```

also prints,

```
[]
```

but then why use this form if it is the same as using normal list notation?
I thought this was strange because I thought "()" is a tuple.

Comment: `([],)` (or just `[],`) would be a tuple containing a list - the _comma_ is what matters. There's _no_ difference between `[]` and `([])` in what you've posted. _"why use this form"_ - we don't know why you used that form.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that might be one of the most confusing aspects of Python. It goes out of its way to make you think the parentheses are the defining characteristic of a tuple, but it turns out to be the comma in the end.